# Valid mountain array using Binary Search

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to solve valid mountain array question in leetcode using Binary Search, but all the test cases are not passing with this approach. Could anyone help me on that.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean validMountainArray(int[] arr) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length - 1;
        int mid = -1;
        while (start < end) {
            mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if (arr[mid] > arr[mid+1] && arr[mid] > arr[start] && arr[mid] > arr[end]) {
                return true;
            } else if (arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]) {
                end = mid;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

I am expecting for all test cases are passes

Comment: Can you share the actual question?

Comment: It would be polite to include a link to the LeetCode page with this problem.  Is it this one?  https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-mountain-array/description/

Comment: What have you done to test this? I suggest you look at the description of the problem, come up with some of your own test cases, including some edge cases. Run your code to see if they pass or fail. If you are still stuck, update the question with examples of where your code passes and where your code fails.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: You can't use binary search like that since you don't know where the peak of the mountain is.

Comment: one requirement for binary search is having an ordered array - based on the ordering, it will ignore part of the array  - for this particular problem it will not check the ignored part, consequently not good for determining if the array is a valid mountain array

Comment: P.S. If you do find test cases that fail, you will learn more if you debugged the problem before asking for help. If you want to become a software developer, or otherwise regularly develop software, debugging will be a necessary skill.

Comment: @Progman, I partially disagree. **If** the array is a mountain array, it should be possible to find the peak with a modified binary search: If `arr[mid+1] > arr[mid]`, the peak must be to the right of `arr[mid]`. If `arr[mid-1] < arr[mid]`, the peak must be to the left of `arr[mid]`. But, binary search is inadequate for determining if `arr` qualifies as a mountain array. If it is not a valid mountain array, there is no guarantee a binary search will find the peak.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot binary search on a function that checks if a particular index is a mountain peak, as it is not monotonic. Instead, you can verify the conditions with a linear loop over the array. After reaching the first point where the mountain height decreases from the previous one, it must never increase again.

Sample implementation:

```java
public boolean validMountainArray(int[] arr) {
    boolean down = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) return false;
        // strictly increasing/decreasing must have no equal elements
        if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) {
            if (i == 1) return false; // has not starting increasing yet
            down = true; // mark as started decreasing
        } else if (down) return false;
        // increasing again after already starting decreasing
    }
    return down; // must have decreasing segment at the end
}
```